# Массовое удаление белого фона в tiff

Tags: photoshop

Есть порядка 5000 съемок с беспилотника, но проблема в том, что фон не прозрачный, а белый. Есть ли инструмент для автоматического массового удаления фона (заменить на прозрачный) ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такое гораздо проще написать самому.

Comment: [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#transparent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Через photoshop как вариант:

5000 - файлов это много, займет много времени. Скорее всего придется делать по группам, разделить по количеству картинки по 500 например. Зависит от характеристик ПК

Операция удаления фона - [Download Transparent Channels Photoshop Action .zip](http://www.freewillunlimited.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Transparent-Channels-v1.0.zip)

*Как это работает можно посмотреть на записи ниже:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### Автоматизация процесса:

Для того чтобы автоматизировать процесс необходимо записать повторяющий сценарий.

Для этого нажмите сочетание клавиш "Alt + F9" далее выберите:

- [image: введите сюда описание изображения] - "Записать новую  операцию"

После чего откроется окно:

- [image: Элемент списка]

Введите имя операции, выберите набор по умолчанию и нажмите "**Записать**".

*После чего вам необходимо будет выполнить нужные вам действия над изображением, в вашем случаи удаление фона.*

Для этого выберите в меню: `"Изображение" -> "Режим" -> "CMYK"` дальше нажмите `"Alt + F9"`  и запустите операцию  `"CMYK > Trans Layer"` после перейдите в слои и удалите ненужный слой с белым фоном и нажмите на кнопку  [image: введите сюда описание изображения] -"**стоп**". Готово, ваша новая операция находится в меню операций `"Alt + F9"` с названием которым вы указали.

Так же вы можете записать сохранения готового файла.